# How to prevent a file in linux from being changed

Tags: php, linux, file, permissions, centos

I've installed a CMS on my CentOS which changes a file constantly. And I want to prevent it from being changed.
I tried:

```
chattr +i file.php
```

Or:

```
chmod 444 file.php
```

Even I've tried copying file(as file.php2) and then mounting it:

```
mount --bind file.php2 file.php -o ro
```

Then how can I prevent my file from being changed by that CMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must

- prevent others than owner to write the file :

`chmod 644 file.php`

- you must set the *ownership* of the file **to a different user and group than the user running the CMS**

`chown root:root file.php`

- Additionnaly, prevent others than owner to write to directory :

`chmod 755 /path/to/dir/containing/`

- Additionnaly, change owner of folder to another user/group

`chown root:root /path/to/dir/containing/`

Why work on the folder too ?

Because a user having write rights on a folder can delete any other user's files, even if he couldn't write to it or read it. As a consequence, if you do not change the folder's permission too, the CMS user could delete your 'protected' file and write another one in its place.

Edit: and of course, your CMS shouldn't run as root, or all the above would be ignored

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo chmod 400 file.php` This will make the file non editable to other users.

Comment: Try to figure out from where that file get changed from CMS

Comment: how should i do that? is there any way to understand which file of cms changed file.php?

Comment: search through your all cms files in editor for ex. php file functions like fopen or that file name. so that you track it

Comment: files are encrypted